# Custom HTML tag on Load in GTM with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to inject events into the data layer when DOM pages load on my website. Since I don't have access to the website code and the developers don't want to add this I'm trying to implement it through a custom HTML in tag manager. I'm not an expert in javascript and I don't understand why the syntax below keeps giving me an error saying

> 'The value is not properly formatted'

I have tried different options:
Option 1:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

(function getPageType () {
    {% if template.name == "index" %}
    return "Homepage";
    {% elsif search.performed %}
    return "Search Results";
    {% elsif template.name == "collection" %}
    return "Collection Page";
    {% elsif template.name == "product" %}
    return "Product Detail Page";
    {% elsif template.name == "checkout" %}
    return "Checkout Page";
    {% else %}
    return 'Other';
    {% endif %};
    
     
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  
{% if customer %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "VisitorType": "Logged In",
    "visitorId": "{{ customer.id | remove: "'" }}",
    "CustomerId": "{{ customer.id | remove: "'" }}",
    "CustomerEmail": "{{ customer.email }}",
    "CustomerFirstName": "{{ customer.first_name }}",
    "CustomerLastName": "{{ customer.last_name }}",
    "CustomerOrdersCount": "{{ customer.orders_count }}",
    "CustomerTotalSpent": "{{ customer.total_spent | divided_by: 100 }}",
  });
  {% else %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "VisitorType": "Guest"
  });
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if template.name == "index" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "event": "HomeView",
    "pageType": "home"
  });
  {% elsif search.performed %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "searchresults"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "collection" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "category"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "product" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "product"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "cart" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "cart"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "checkout" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "checkout"
  });
  {% else %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "other"
  });
  {% endif %}

    
    {% if checkout.discounts_amount %}
        var discounts = [];
        {% for discount in checkout.discounts %}
            discount = {};
            discount.code = "{{ discount.code }}";
            discount.amount = "{{ discount.amount | times: 0.01 }}";
            discount.savings = "{{ discount.savings | times: 0.01 }}";
            discount.title = "{{ discount.title }}";
            discount.type = "{{ discount.title }}";
            discounts.push(discount);
        {% endfor %}
        if(discounts.length) {
        window.dataLayer.push({
        "discounts": discounts,
        });
        }
        {% if checkout.discounts_amount %}
            window.dataLayer.push({
            "discountTotalAmount": "{{ checkout.discounts_amount }}",
            });
        {% endif %}
        {% if checkout.discounts_savings %}
            window.dataLayer.push({
            "discountTotalSavings": "{{ checkout.discounts_savings }}",
            });
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if checkout %}
        var step = null;
        {% if page_title contains "Information" %}
            step = 1;
            {% elsif page_title contains "Shipping" %}
            step = 2;
            {% elsif page_title contains "Payment" %}
            step = 3;
        {% endif %}
    
        dataLayer.push({
        "event": "checkout",
        "cartTotal": "{{ checkout.total_price | money_without_currency | remove:',' }}",
        "ecommerce": {
        "currencyCode": "{{ shop.currency }}",
        "checkout": {
        "actionField": {
        step: step
        },
        "products": [
        {% for line_item in checkout.line_items %}
            {
            "name": "{{ line_item.product.title | escape }}",
            "id": "{{ line_item.sku }}",
            "productId": "{{ line_item.product_id }}",
            "variantId": "{{ line_item.variant_id }}",
            "price": "{{ line_item.price | times: 0.01 }}",
            "brand": "{{ line_item.vendor | escape  }}",
            "category": "{{ line_item.product.type | escape  }}",
            "variant": "{{ line_item.variant.title | escape }}",
            "quantity": "{{ line_item.quantity }}"
            },
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        }
        }
        });
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if order %}
        window.dataLayer.push({
        "orderEmail": "{{ order.email }}",
        "orderName": "{{ order.name }}",
        "orderNumber": "{{ order.order_number }}",
        "orderTotalPrice": "{{ order.total_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderTaxPrice": "{{ order.tax_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderSubTotalPrice": "{{ order.subtotal_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderShippingPrice": "{{ order.shipping_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderLineItems": [
        {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
            {
            "name": "{{line_item.product.title | escape}}",
            "id": "{{line_item.sku}}",
            "price": "{{line_item.price | times: 0.01}}",
            "brand": "{{line_item.vendor}}",
            "category": "{{line_item.type}}",
            "variant": "{{line_item.variant.title | escape}}",
            "quantity": "{{ line_item.quantity }}"
            },
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        });
    {% endif %}
    
    window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "checkout",
    });
     
    });
     
    })();

  
   </script>
```

Option 2:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    
  function getPageType() {
    {% if template.name == "index" %}
    return "Homepage";
    {% elsif search.performed %}
    return "Search Results";
    {% elsif template.name == "collection" %}
    return "Collection Page";
    {% elsif template.name == "product" %}
    return "Product Detail Page";
    {% elsif template.name == "checkout" %}
    return "Checkout Page";
    {% else %}
    return 'Other';
    {% endif %}
  }
  
  {% if customer %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "VisitorType": "Logged In",
    "visitorId": "{{ customer.id | remove: "'" }}",
    "CustomerId": "{{ customer.id | remove: "'" }}",
    "CustomerEmail": "{{ customer.email }}",
    "CustomerFirstName": "{{ customer.first_name }}",
    "CustomerLastName": "{{ customer.last_name }}",
    "CustomerOrdersCount": "{{ customer.orders_count }}",
    "CustomerTotalSpent": "{{ customer.total_spent | divided_by: 100 }}",
  });
  {% else %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "VisitorType": "Guest"
  });
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if template.name == "index" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "event": "HomeView",
    "pageType": "home"
  });
  {% elsif search.performed %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "searchresults"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "collection" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "category"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "product" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "product"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "cart" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "cart"
  });
  {% elsif template.name == "checkout" %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "checkout"
  });
  {% else %}
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "other"
  });
  {% endif %}

    
    {% if checkout.discounts_amount %}
        var discounts = [];
        {% for discount in checkout.discounts %}
            discount = {};
            discount.code = "{{ discount.code }}";
            discount.amount = "{{ discount.amount | times: 0.01 }}";
            discount.savings = "{{ discount.savings | times: 0.01 }}";
            discount.title = "{{ discount.title }}";
            discount.type = "{{ discount.title }}";
            discounts.push(discount);
        {% endfor %}
        if(discounts.length) {
        window.dataLayer.push({
        "discounts": discounts,
        });
        }
        {% if checkout.discounts_amount %}
            window.dataLayer.push({
            "discountTotalAmount": "{{ checkout.discounts_amount }}",
            });
        {% endif %}
        {% if checkout.discounts_savings %}
            window.dataLayer.push({
            "discountTotalSavings": "{{ checkout.discounts_savings }}",
            });
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if checkout %}
        var step = null;
        {% if page_title contains "Information" %}
            step = 1;
            {% elsif page_title contains "Shipping" %}
            step = 2;
            {% elsif page_title contains "Payment" %}
            step = 3;
        {% endif %}
    
        dataLayer.push({
        "event": "checkout",
        "cartTotal": "{{ checkout.total_price | money_without_currency | remove:',' }}",
        "ecommerce": {
        "currencyCode": "{{ shop.currency }}",
        "checkout": {
        "actionField": {
        step: step
        },
        "products": [
        {% for line_item in checkout.line_items %}
            {
            "name": "{{ line_item.product.title | escape }}",
            "id": "{{ line_item.sku }}",
            "productId": "{{ line_item.product_id }}",
            "variantId": "{{ line_item.variant_id }}",
            "price": "{{ line_item.price | times: 0.01 }}",
            "brand": "{{ line_item.vendor | escape  }}",
            "category": "{{ line_item.product.type | escape  }}",
            "variant": "{{ line_item.variant.title | escape }}",
            "quantity": "{{ line_item.quantity }}"
            },
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        }
        }
        });
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if order %}
        window.dataLayer.push({
        "orderEmail": "{{ order.email }}",
        "orderName": "{{ order.name }}",
        "orderNumber": "{{ order.order_number }}",
        "orderTotalPrice": "{{ order.total_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderTaxPrice": "{{ order.tax_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderSubTotalPrice": "{{ order.subtotal_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderShippingPrice": "{{ order.shipping_price | divided_by: 100 }}",
        "orderLineItems": [
        {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
            {
            "name": "{{line_item.product.title | escape}}",
            "id": "{{line_item.sku}}",
            "price": "{{line_item.price | times: 0.01}}",
            "brand": "{{line_item.vendor}}",
            "category": "{{line_item.type}}",
            "variant": "{{line_item.variant.title | escape}}",
            "quantity": "{{ line_item.quantity }}"
            },
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        });
    {% endif %}
    
    window.dataLayer.push({
    "pageType": "checkout",
    });

  }, false);
</script>
```

Why those are not working?

Answer (score 0):

You're generally not supposed to push events in DL from GTM. There are exclusions when it's useful, but it's mostly for non-standard events and polling.

Judging from the code, you don't need it here either. In your code you're adding explicit window load listeners. Don't.

1. Make a tag that would load on pageview. This is instead of custom listeners.
2. Create empty CJS variable for every custom field you want to set.
3. Fill event/pageview fields with references to custom JS variables.
4. In the CJS variables, you do all the local parsing you need and return the desired result.

Also I would advise against using templates and this kind of syntax: {% elsif template.name == "cart" %} unless you really can't do without them. Reasoning behind it is that it's very simple to implement the logic in pure JS, but you lose the so very comfortable ability to actually check the code against your local console. This doesn't concern local GTM variables: {{ }}.